# applying any formula by column wise

Tags: r

Now how to apply `ifelse` statement on all columns dynamically starting from column 3

```
Date    name   A      B    C    XYZ  
2014    sam    22     0    -1   20  
2015    john   -1     29    0   40
```

We can do it by hard coding , excluding 1 and 2 columns

```
df1$A = ifelse(df$A <= 0 ,NA,df$A)   #to
df1$XYZ = ifelse(df$XYZ <= 0 ,NA,df$XYZ)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can use `lapply` i.e. `df1[3:ncol(df1)] <- lapply(df1[3:ncol(df1)], function(x) ifelse(x <=0, NA, x))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `base R`, we can loop through the columns of interest, apply the `ifelse` and assign it back to those columns

```
df1[3:ncol(df1)] <- lapply(df1[3:ncol(df1)], function(x) ifelse(x <=0, NA, x))
```

---

However, we can do this more easily without any looping or `ifelse`

```
df1[3:ncol(df1)][df1[3:ncol(df1)] <=0] <- NA
```

Comment: for(i in 3:ncol(df))
{
  a[,i]<-ifelse(df[,i]<=0,"",df[,i])
  
}

Comment: i can do that with above loop

Comment: Thanks for ur help akrun

Answer (score 0):

Using `dplyr`/`tidyverse`:

```
library(tidyverse)

df1 = df1 %>%
    mutate_at(vars(A:XYZ), function(x) { ifelse(x <= 0, NA, x)})
```

Output:

```
  Date name  A  B  C XYZ
1 2014  sam 22 NA NA  20
2 2015 john NA 29 NA  40
```